# Where should I put translation lists in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm fetching table names and column names from a database and then put them in drop-downs. To be a little nice to my users I'm about to translating the table and column names to something that a normal human can understand.

My problem is that i don't know where I should put the translation lists.

- In another database (because I can't make changes in the one I'm reading from)? But that just feels wrong.
- In the model? But I don't want to load a lot of unnecessary data when I use methods that don't need to translate.
- In a separate helper? That way I can load the helper when I need to translate.

Any other suggestions (with pros and cons)?

Comment: Do you know, that Codeigniter has [Language class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html) that works with translations in language files?
But its your choice where tu put your translations, all variants has pros and cons.

Comment: Hmm... using the language class seems to be overkill for what I'm trying to achieve. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Overkill? Why? That's exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Maybe I haven't read it through properly. I thought it was for when I need translations to multiple languages. I will only translate to English. For example: D2001 -> Part number

Comment: There is nothing wrong to use language class for single language website. You don't need to code any new library and it's easy to understand for anybody who is working on your app (and who is familiar with codeigniter).

Comment: I made my own solution... but after some thinking I tested the Language class and it was much better! Thanks for convincing me! If you write it as an answer I will accept the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I wrote in my comment, the best way to achieve this is to use Codeigniter [Language class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html).

Then you create **tables_lang.php** file in language directory.

Next you load language file:

```
$this->lang->load('tables', 'english');
```

or (if you want to use default language):

```
$this->lang->load('tables');
```

If you have table **users**, in that table column **name**, your language lines should look like this:

```
$lang['table_users'] = 'Users table';
$lang['table_users_col_name'] = 'User name';
```

In your controller, model or view you can fetch data this way:

```
$table = 'users'; //table name from database
$table_name = $this->lang->line('table_'.$table);

$column = 'name';
$column_name = $this->lang->line('table_'.$table.'_col_'.$column);
```

If you want to use translations in your view, you have to change `$this->lang->line()` to `lang()` function from language helper.